# How can I determine the source of these notifications? (macOS)

Tags: macos, notifications

How can I determine the source of these notifications? I don't have any app that is called "Computing on Demand" and I can't find any reference to it on the Internet. I've thought about turning off all notifications and turning back on one by one but I'm not sure that would turn them off if its malicious.

[image: Notifications]

Comment: Well, it’s defiantly a app, that’s loaded and sending notifications.  Take a look at your login items (Settings -> User) and post what you see.  Next, create another user and see if the app is there too.  That will tell us if it’s limited to your account or not.  But, it sounds like a Malware, so I’d also download and run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Allan. FYI I ran Malwarebytes and it came up with nothing. I have checked login items and there's nothing obvious - see here: https://imgur.com/a/PiBxd6N . I'm looking through the LaunchAgents - nothing obvious there. I've yet to try the other ideas.

Comment: You’ve got a lot of extra “stuff” there.  Try disabling all,  see if it goes away, then re-enable each one, one-by-one, until the problem returns.  Leave an hour or so between each app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompted by the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387252/313842) here, it's a good idea to check

- System Preferences > Notifications.
- Safari Preferences > Websites, notifications tab. Same for all other browsers.
- Browser extensions.
- Search term "computing on demand", "computing" or similar, using apps like [EasyFind](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) in the `~/Library` Folder first, then the whole computer.

Comment: the safari prefs websites notifications tab looks promising - there was an entry for computing on demand. I've removed it and waiting to see if this fixes it. Can sites send notifications even when I don't have the page open? Its not a site that I can ever remember having visited and certainly not something I have open at the time I receive notification.

Comment: Apparently sites can send notifications even when the page isn't open and they're called "Web Push Notifications"

Comment: Yes that is correct, push notifications work that way, just like on mobile. When the app is not open, but you get a ping. Most probably, it was disguised as a reliable website which you allowed notifications of.

Comment: This was the answer for me, it was in Safari, Settings Websites, notifications.

Answer (score 2):

https://computingondemand.com/ 
Found this website.

You can also get notifications from websites on your system. Maybe go to the website and check if the notifications are enabled. Click the lock icon to see the notification status. [image][image: screenshot on how to check notification status]

Comment: I've had my browsers (Firefox and Safari)  on that site for about 45 mins now and neither have asked me to allow notifications.  There's no link and the icons look completely different.  Are you *sure* you've got the right site?  Also, what the OP posted (content wise) is completely different than the content of the site.

Comment: @Allan Since he said he can't find anything on the internet by that name, I guessed he missed it. I'm not sure if it's the right website... Just wanted him to check. The above answer looks right. ✌

Comment: @Allan and OP  Interestingly when I did follow the [answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387293/369624) I found that I had an entry in safari notification preferences for "computing on demand" - I've removed them and giving it a go. I didn't know that a site would be able to send notifications when I don't have the site open in Safari - its not something I have open when notifications appear (or that I can remember visiting, ever!)

Answer (score 2):

Open the macOS Console application here `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/`. Then search for any these key phrases:

- `Added notification request`
- `Adding notification request`
- `pending notification`
- `Getting pending notification requests`

When you find the notification events in the system log, you can identify which process and bundle ID is generating the notification events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nic - I've been searching through the logs but nothing yet...