# How to get rid of these random Norton antivirus notifications on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, notifications

To be clear I have never installed Norton Antivirus software on my MacBook and now I have received three notifications via Chrome browser that my Norton antivirus has expired.

What does this mean and how do I stop it? I looked inside of Notifications in Chrome Browser and I have nothing enabled for Norton antivirus messages. Where are these messages coming from then?

Comment: Are any of the answers here helpful for you? [How  can I determine the source of these notifications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387249/18101)

Answer (score 1):

My eyes missed it. Inside of Google Chrome notification I had a `www.goodbiz.com` type of site where I was receiving the notifications from. I removed it.

Comment: Run the free [Malwarebytes app](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) to discover and eradicate any malware which may be lurking. My mother's Mac had problems of this ilk, and she runs Malwarebytes religiously now.

Comment: @IconDaemon there's no suggestion of malware in this case. Just accidentally allowed notifications from an undesirable website.

Comment: @Nic, yes, I believe that is what happened.